# Lining Up Divs in a dynamic grid

Tags: html, css

Click [here](http://i40.tinypic.com/kd1ys0.jpg) to view the page in question.

Is there a way to make the divs line up in a dynamic grid?  Meaning they always are equidistant to eachother, no matter how much their height is?

Comment: Six or Nine per page, I think will be the limit.

Comment: Is what you want something like this? http://www.ruzee.com/blog/2007/05/align-list-items-horizontally-with-css

Comment: Like this: http://i39.tinypic.com/o3hw2.jpg

Comment: If you want the divs to be offset like bricks in a wall as in your illustration, you will probably need to look into Javascript, like here: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/08/04/fullscreen-grid-portfolio/ ...But if lining them up so the tops are flat is okay, see the new link I gave above.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understood your question correctly, but if i did you're trying to understand how to create a grid of objects (such as a table).

You would usually have a wrapper div to define the the width of the "restriction" , and inside it place elements that are all "floating" to the left, and in that way, they will collapse to the next row when there is no more room. (There is no problem in changing any of the element's height to something different than 100px, and they would still be attached to each other by float)

You can see a sample in the following link:
http://jsfiddle.net/UkBFr/1/

Shai.

Comment: The heights of the divs will sometimes have different heights.  The widths will always be the same.  So a perfect grid isn't possible.  I need the top of the second row divs to line up to the bottom of the div above it, basically.  It's really hard to explain. :)

Comment: Maybe upload some illustration of what you're trying to do ? I think messing with my example a bit will get you where you need :)

Comment: There are many solutions for that, easiest solution i think would be to either push those divs 10px down with relative positioning : http://jsfiddle.net/UkBFr/4/  , Or use jQuery to change the css of only the "middle" objects, if you don't want to use a class for all second objects.